# Compile CGAL for iOS / alternate 2D cad library?

Tags: iphone, ios, geometry, computational-geometry, cgal

I'm hoping to make use of [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) in an iOS / iPad app. I'm a reasonably experienced iOS developer, but I haven't ever tried including a C++ library such as this one, and I haven't actually used CGAL before. Extensive research has shown it to be the best option for me (I need a free/open source license and a wide range of 2D geometry methods, including tangent/normal vectors at arbitrary points on a bezier, bezier offset, bezier intersection, etc. I'm particularly drawn to `CGAL's` "arrangements" which let you do boolean operations with closed spaces, though that feature is not a make-or-break feature). I am open to other alternatives, but I have looked into dozens of libraries to arrive at this one -- I'd prefer this discussion to be about CGAL than other suggestions, unless you have a particularly compelling reason to suggest another direction.

Ideally, I'm hoping someone can give me some step-by-step guidance on how to get to the "hello world" of `CGAL` in iOS.... generating a line between two points, perhaps. I don't need `CGAL` to do the rendering for me, but I'd also be open to suggestions from anyone who has attempted similar combinations of elements before. I'm using a current version of Xcode, and would like to stick with `LLVM` compiling (which `CGAL` in theory now supports).

Comment: The LLVM support is not only there in theory ;) I'd recommend taking this to the CGAL discuss list as it seem as rather open question to me.

Answer (score 1):

CGAL does support Apple llvm/clang, but only on MacOS X, so far. The reason is that the internals of the CGAL kernel need a special support for the Floating Point Unit. That support was never tried so far for CPUs running iOS.